# Android targetSdkVersion=19 causes improper layout among ListView elements

Tags: android, api, listview, layout

I have an app that works great when I declare `targetSdkVersion="17"`.  I just upgraded my dev environment to API 19 and ran into an immediate issue that doesn't cause an exception, but causes weird formatting issues.  There is a lot of unintended whitespace in each element now.  Sometimes it is near my `ImageView` objects, other times it happens when the `ImageView` is characterized by `setVisibility(View.GONE)`.  Any idea what may be causing this? The only change between the images below is setting the targetSdkVersion and everything works as desired on API 17.  Also, this seems to affect my Nexus 4 (which is `xdpi`) and not the emulator I've been using, which is just `hdpi`.

[Compare this (API 17)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeCdN.png) to [this (API 19)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCppm.png)

[another example (API 17)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mHSQ.png) to [this (API 19)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWCVs.png)

Here is my list_item.xml file where the layout for each element is defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="6dip" android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@color/plain_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/share_image"  
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_share"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="30dp"
        android:maxWidth="30dp"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:minWidth="30dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/created_modifed_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/share_image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"        
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"                
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/created"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#0033FF"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"        
        android:textSize="@dimen/secondaryFontSize" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_modified"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#D80000"   
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"       
        android:textSize="@dimen/secondaryFontSize" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView  
     android:id="@+id/contents"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/share_image"
     android:layout_below="@id/created_modifed_layout"
     android:textColor="#303030"     
     android:singleLine="false"
     android:ellipsize="none"
     android:scrollHorizontally="false"
     android:textSize="@dimen/mainFontSize"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contents_image" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/description_contents_image"       
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/contents"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/imgur_url"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#303030"     
    android:layout_below="@+id/contents_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textSize="@dimen/secondaryFontSize" />

<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/downloadImgurProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/contents"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large.Inverse"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
        android:progress="0"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239547/android-sdk-18-textview-gravity-doesnt-work-vertically

Comment: @cgr Thank you for the response! I've not worked on that project for a while now but it's nice to know someone else found a good workaround.