# Android sdk 18 TextView gravity doesn't work vertically

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a probleme with the SDK 18.
The gravity of my text view doesn't work vertically. But it's working with sdk17.

Pictures and code :

header_of_listView.xml :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/entete.size.h"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/blank"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/cellule_flecher_mise_en_valeur" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/a_remplacer"
            android:textColor="@color/tableviewText"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

[image: sdk = 17]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

[image: sdk = 18]

with black background for textview
android:background="#000000"

[image: sdk 18 with black background]

If someone have an idea.
I have try to change wrap_content with match_parent.

The only thing that work is
android:layout_height="@dimen/entete.size.h" on the TextView, but the margin doesn't apply.
For the moment I leave the project to SDK 17.

Comment: remove  android:targetSdkVersion="18" and run....

Comment: It's work. But i have the warning  "tag should specify a target API level (the highest verified version; when running on later 
 versions, compatibility behaviors may be enabled) with android:targetSdkVersion="?" "

Comment: It doesn't bother as u have min sdk specified...

Comment: I have the exact same bug. Did you found any solution? instead of set targetSdk to 17

Comment: also match_parent for heigth has no effect, it is still wrapped

Comment: I checked it again: the problem is not the TaxtView, it is the ListView / GridView!!! if I move this TextView into a different RelativLayout outside of the List/Grid-View it looks like it should...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the RelativLayout as root layout of the listview item. If your put a LinearLayout around the RelativeLayout it works also with targetSdk = 19.
Same problem appears with the GridView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   ... your layout like before

</LinearLayout>
```

This is not really a nice workaround - but better than put targetSdk = 17 I guess.

Comment: I had the same problem as the original poster but with a TextView inside a CardView inside a RecyclerView. Wrapping the entire CardView layout in a match_parent LinearLayout fixed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I was wrong, that didn't fix it for me. The cards started being as wide as the parent, which isn't what I wanted. I had to wrap one of the RelativeLayouts inside the CardView element, in a useless LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it happened only in Android 19. I target api 23 and it works fine.

I found out that giving a height to the textview fixed the problem

It was like this:

```
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/a_remplacer"
            android:textColor="@color/tableviewText"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

I made it like this:

```
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"            <!-- this is the key-->      
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/iv_bg"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/a_remplacer"
            android:textColor="@color/tableviewText"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

I didn't want to add another linear layout because of performance issues.

Answer (score -4):

remove `android:targetSdkVersion="18"` and run.

Comment: I'm loosing tablette compatibility

Comment: This is nuts... sorry but this answer is so wrong that it doesn't deserve to be called an answer!