# TextView gravity not working on API 18 or higher

Tags: android, api, textview, gravity

I have an TextView wich overlaps some other view. Everything works great, except the gravity on API equal or higher than 18.

Here is my TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/overlappingTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/behindLinearLayout"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/behindLinearLayout"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/behindLinearLayout"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/behindLinearLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/overlapping_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Waiting for user confirmation..."
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />
```

The gravity works ok on 4.2.2 or lower but is not working on 4.3 and higher ... It works only partially, it is centered but only vertically.

[image: On API 4.1.2]
[image: On API 4.3]
LE:

There is no fix for this issue? Or does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I would recommend posting some screenshots and including the entire layout in which this `TextView` exists.

Comment: Will make some screenshots and will update the question soon. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue in API 18+, and there's a workaround involving wrapping your view in a LinearLayout.

See the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22812527/3412775) thread.

In your case, the fixed code should look something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/behindLinearLayout"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/behindLinearLayout"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/behindLinearLayout"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/behindLinearLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/overlapping_bg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/overlappingTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Waiting for user confirmation..."
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

</LinearLayout>
```