# android:gravity in TextView not working

Tags: android, textview

When i apply android:gravity to center(or even textAlignment true for TextView) , the instant changes are applied to current activity (using my device for testing) and the text is centered .

But then when i install/restart app with the same changes (or come back to present activity from previous one), the text is left aligned at the start of the TextView .

TextView trying to center : android:id="@+id/ttamt

The text is centered only when i make changes while running app on the activity.

Really can't understand what wrong i am doing here ,

Thanks for your time and help .

Following is my layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainRel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#5f5f5f"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:transitionName="@string/transtrans">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ttimg"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_tooltip_blue_topnub"
            android:transitionName="timgTrans" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ttamt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ttimg"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1001"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="55sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:transitionName="tamtTrans" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ttdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ttamt"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/timg"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="01/01/01"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ttdesc"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="TestDesc"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:transitionName="tdescTrans" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_black_24dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ttmsg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:text="View SMS"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: File -> Invalidete Cache & Restart . Sometimes android studio bugs out and keeps the old changes. (Build-> Rebuild project might do the trick as well)

Comment: Build ->Clean ,or Re Build your project

Comment: None of it is helping , the text center is only happening when i rerun app activity(instant changes) after making changes (adding `android:gravity="center"`) to present code which does not have `android:gravity="center"` .

Comment: tried rebuilding and the invalidate cache thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue with api 18 or higher after seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22812920/3820753) answer.

Did the same , wrapped my views inside LinearLayout and used textAlignment="center" . Works fine now .

Final Layout Snippet :

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainRel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#5f5f5f"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:transitionName="@string/transtrans">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ttimg"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_tooltip_blue_topnub"
        android:transitionName="timgTrans" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ttamt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ttimg"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="1001"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="55sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:transitionName="tamtTrans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ttdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ttamt"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="01/01/01"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```